# Python read cell range

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm learning python and at the moment I am working with openpyxl.
I'm trying to get the single values of a range, but cell_range prints only some weird values like (<Cell 'rom'.A5>, <Cell 'rom'.B5>, <Cell 'rom'.C5>). Instead of this I want to get the value behind these arguments e.g. 'rom'.A5

The tutorial https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html only shows how to get e.g Cell 'rom.A5.
Which command do I have to use to get the real value of the cell stored in 'rom'.A5, 'rom'.B5 and 'rom'.C5
I know how to use it in an other way for example with ws.cell(row,col).value, but I want to do it with the range example.

Thank you for your help

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'

ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "range names"

ws2 = wb.create_sheet("numbers", 0)
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("do_it",1)

ws2.title = "rom"
ws1.sheet_properties.tabColor = "FF0000"

ws4 = wb["do_it"]

wb.copy_worksheet(ws2) 
ws2['A4'] = 3
c = ws1['A4']
ws2.cell(5,1,4)
ws2.cell(5,2,5)
ws2.cell(5,3,6)
cell_range = ws2['A5':'C5']

for value in cell_range:
    print(value)


wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not in an image.

Comment: Rather than explaining here, it would be easier for you to go through the tutorial on openpyxl. This link **https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python**  will explain how to access individual cells and ranges and  cell value as opposed to the cell object which is what your printing.

Comment: Hey Charlie, the link you shared is completely the same and it doesn't answer my question.. My problem is that I get objects like (<Cell 'rom'.A5>, <Cell 'rom'.B5>, <Cell 'rom'.C5>) when I print cell_range... This does not help me if I for example want to calculate 5*Cell 'rom".B5.. I need the value of the cell itself, here B5. Cell 'rom'.B5.value does not work what do I have to do to get the value of any cell innert the range A5-C5..

Answer (score 0):

Following is my feedback to solve this situation:
My Data set: [Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGDwa.png)

```
# Import openpyxl
# Note: openpyxl package provides both read and write capabilities to excel
import openpyxl
import os
import string


# Class definitions should use CamelCase convention based on pep-8 guidelines
class CustomOpenpyxl:

    # Initialize the class with filename as only argument
    def __init__(self, _my_file_name):
        assert _my_file_name.split('.')[-1] == 'xlsx', 'Input file is not xlsx'
        self.my_filename = _my_file_name
        self.my_base_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.my_filename, read_only=False)

    # Method to create a dictionary of column letters and index position
    # Works for a maximum 26 columns
    def get_col_idx_and_col_letter_map(self):
        _my_map = dict()
        for _idx, _val in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1):
            _my_map[_val] = _idx
        return _my_map

    # Return Value is
    '''
    {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9, 'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12, 'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17, 'R': 18, 'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24, 'Y': 25, 'Z': 26}
    '''


# we are using the in-built os package and getcwd() method
_my_file_path = os.getcwd()
_my_file_name = 'Book1.xlsx'

# Instantiate an object using the newly created class in this code block
# So that this object gets access to all methods in the class
_my_src_obj = CustomOpenpyxl(_my_file_name)

# Variablize the start and end range for avoiding further needs of string curation
_start_range = 'F3'
_end_range = 'H6'
# Define cell range on your active worksheet
_cell_range = _my_src_obj.my_base_wb['Sheet2'][_start_range:_end_range]

# Parse the start range to separate column letter and column number
_start_rng_col = ''.join([_ for _ in _start_range if _.isupper()])
_start_rng_row = ''.join([_ for _ in _start_range if _.isdigit()])
'''
returns : ['F', '3']
'''
_end_rng_col = ''.join([_ for _ in _end_range if _.isupper()])
_end_rng_row = ''.join([_ for _ in _end_range if _.isdigit()])
'''
returns : ['H', '6']
'''
# Iterating over the rows and fetching values only
# and using the min_col, min_row, max_col and max_row values derived earlier
for _val in _my_src_obj.my_base_wb['Sheet2'].iter_rows(values_only=True, min_col= int(_my_src_obj.get_col_idx_and_col_letter_map()[_start_rng_col]),
                                                    max_col=int(_my_src_obj.get_col_idx_and_col_letter_map()[_end_rng_col]),
                                                    min_row=int(_start_rng_row),
                                                    max_row=int(_end_rng_row)):
    print(_val)
    #####################################################RESULT
    ('USA', 1, None)
    ('Canada', 2, 'Yahoo')
    ('Mexico', 2, 'Google')
    ('Brazil', 4, 'Microsoft')
```